# cairo_text_extents_t is not recognized by lua

Tags: lua, cairo, conky

I am writing some widget in lua to be used by `conky` to display some stuff.
I reached a point in which I would like to center text. Following [this](https://www.cairographics.org/samples/text_align_center/) tutorial, I ported the `C` code into `lua` code, so it now looks like this:

```
local extents
local utf8 = "cairo"
local x, y
cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
cairo_set_font_size(cr, 13)
cairo_text_extents(cr, utf8, extents)
x = 128.0 - (extents.width / 2 + extents.x_bearing)
y = 128.0 - (extents.height / 2 + extents.y_bearing)

cairo_move_to(cr, x, y)
cairo_show_text(cr, utf8)
```

The problem I am dealing with now is that the `C` data type `cairo_text_extents_t` that should be passed to the `cairo_text_extents` is not recognized by `lua`, in fact `conky` closes without any output.

Is there a way to make `lua` recognize that data type?

Comment: I guess you need to do `local extents={}` or `extents = cairo_text_extents(cr, utf8)`.

Comment: I do not think so, since the function `cairo_text_extents` does not return anything, in fact in `C` you are expected to pass it `&extents`, where `&extents` being the memory address of a variable of type `cairo_text_extents_t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer. In conky there exists a function that does what I need, as specified [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/lua.html):

> `cairo_text_extents_t:create()    function`
>   Call this function to return a new `cairo_text_extents_t` structure. A
>   creation function for this structure is not provided by the cairo API.
>   After calling this, you should use `tolua.takeownership()` on the return
>   value to ensure ownership is passed properly.

So, it is sufficient to do the following:

```
local extents = cairo_text_extents_t:create()
tolua.takeownership(extents)
local utf8 = "cairo"
local x, y
cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
cairo_set_font_size(cr, 52)
cairo_text_extents(cr, utf8, extents)
x = 128.0 - (extents.width / 2 + extents.x_bearing)
y = 128.0 - (extents.height / 2 + extents.y_bearing)

cairo_move_to (cr, x, y)
cairo_show_text (cr, utf8)
```